# How to add image(s) to UIToolBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'd like to add an image to a UIToolBar that a user cannot interact with. It would essentially be just a non-interactive indicator, like a badge.

Is this possible?
If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `UIBarButtonItem` with an Image and add it:

Example:

```
UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

If you don't want the button appearance, try to use:

```
UIBarButtonItem* item = [UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:yourImageView];
```

Comment: I've tried that - the image turns to an outline, like all the other ToolBar items. You can't add a tint either. Plus, buttons can be interacted with, and if not, they're grayed out so the image is useless.

Comment: That worked - thanks. Here's the actual Button declaration though (your syntax is off): UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:MyImageView];

Comment: I found a better solution: use a UIImageView and add it as a subview:  `UIImageView *tmpimg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mypic.png"]]; [toolBar addSubview:tmpimg];` then position the image with a CGRect for the .frame...

Comment: In most cases its better to use a real barItem. E.g. it handles repositioning on rotation itself. You can add a FlexibleSpace and FixedSpace items, to bring it in position.