# Add image to toolbar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926978/how-to-add-images-to-uitoolbar) but I just wanted to know how to do it in swift. I want to add a UIImageView to a toolbar.

Comment: `let button = UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourImageView)`? `let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: yourImage, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourTargetedAction(_:)))`?

Comment: The answer is the same in Swift and Objective-C. It's the same APIs, just a little different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)))
toolBar.items = [button]
```